# Weavenet for kubernetes is showing 0/2

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm very new to kubernetes. I thought i would first get a basic by making hands dirty by "the hard way"
I followed the Linux academy, but at the networking side using weave net i am now stuck !
completely stuck !

kubectl get pods -n kube-system  -->getting the following crash loop back

`````
weave-net-zngp6   1/2       Error              15         37m    ````

some logs for investigating
````kubectl -n kube-system logs weave-net-px6z7 -c weave-npc````

got 
```` Get https://10.32.0.1:443/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1/networkpolicies?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.32.0.1:443: i/o timeout````

Not sure what it means ? any one can save me ?
`````

Answer (score 1):

weave-net is trying unsuccessfully to talk to the apiserver at 10.32.0.1 (port 443). Verify your master node is indeed at that IP address, it has network connectivity to the node where this is barfing, and that the firewall on the master node has port 443 open.

If they are all running on the same host, verify the apiserver is running.